# Was bedeutet „göbeln“?

Tags: meaning, dialect

Ich hörte gerade in einem Hörspiel (»Jonah, der Aufstieg« von Rebecca Gablé)

> Nirgendwo göbelt es sich so komfortabel wie an Bord deines Schiffes, aber ich wünschte der König hätte mich in den Highlands gelassen.

Das Verb erscheint weder im [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/?q=g%C3%B6beln&from=wb) noch im Grimm. Allerdings kennt letzterer [gobeln](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GG21510#XGG21510):

> GOBELN, vb.; vereinzelt bei Fischart belegt, anscheinend mit der bedeutung 'sich balgen, sich streiten'

Kennt jemand dieses Verb und kann seine Bedeutung angeben?

Comment: Kann [hier](https://www.sprachnudel.de/woerterbuch/g%F6beln) nachgeschlagen werden.

Comment: @guidot allein schon der Kommentare wegen lohnt es sich, die Seite zu besuchen: “Opferste wort auf der welt, jetzt hat josh auch noch recht.”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das ist ein Ausdruck aus der Umgangssprache des "mittleren Westens" Deutschlands (Ruhrgebiet, Rheinland) und bedeutet soviel wie

> sich übergeben

und zwar hauptsächlich nach übermäßigem Alkoholgenuss.

Comment: Das passt in der Tat so perfekt, dass ich es schon hoffte.

Comment: Ob genau diese Wortwahl für einen historischen Roman, der im Jahr 1330 in England spielt, wirklich so toll passt, lasse ich dahingestellt.

Comment: Hah! In der Hinsicht passt es natürlich überhaupt nicht. Aber es passt zum Ritter, der die Seefahrt hasst! Bei der sprachlichen Anpassung an England versagt das Hörspiel generell. Ich habe sehr schnell erkannt, dass es auf Deutsch geschrieben wurde, weil gewisse Redensarten sich anders nicht erklären ließen.